# No such file or directory while using os.rename

Tags: python, file-handling, shutil

This is not this question:[Rename script with [Errno2] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107803/rename-script-with-errno2-no-such-file-or-directory)

I am trying to move the images from the folder images to train_images and test_images folders on the basis of corresponding xml file names in train and test folders.
But getting this error consistently:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "Move2.py", line 13, in <module>
 os.rename(src2,dest2)
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/mohit/darkflow/yes/images/DSCN8434.jpg' -> '/home/mohit/darkflow/yes/train_images/DSCN8434.jpg'`

My script is:

```
import os

train=os.listdir("/home/mohit/darkflow/yes/train")
test=os.listdir("/home/mohit/darkflow/yes/test")

path2="/home/mohit/darkflow/yes/images/"
moveto3="/home/mohit/darkflow/yes/train_images/"
moveto4="/home/mohit/darkflow/yes/test_images/"

for f_name in train:
    f_name=f_name.replace(".xml",".jpg")
    src2=path2+f_name
    dest2=moveto3+f_name
    os.rename(src2,dest2)

for f_name2 in test:
    f_name2=f_name2.replace(".xml",".jpg")
    src2=path2+f_name2
    dest=moveto4+f_name2
    os.rename(src2,dest2)
```

- Similar thing happens even if use shutil.move
- I can see that particular image in the image folder for which error is generated.
- Strangely eog imagename does not open it when i am in the images directory

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Where did the spaces between `darkflow` and `/yes` come from?  I see them in the error message but not in the code you posted.

Comment: Also, make sure your destination directory (folder) exists, i.e. `train_images`.

Comment: Yes directory train_images exists and those spaces just came because of my poor writing skills on stack overflow  @TomKarzes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake.

- Actually the image extension was .jpg for some images and .JPG for others.

Solution:

- I changed the less appeared .jpg to .JPG manually and changed .jpg to .JPG in the code as well.

The code did worked

Thank You!